# Upload file for multiple item in the list laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

Below is a screenshot of my project.
[image]

May I ask how can I allow users to upload images for the items in the table? The image wont be updated and stored immediately but will wait until the user clicks the request changes button.

Users might delete some items after they upload the image and then the uploaded image for that item should be deleted as well and not going to update.

Below are some codes of my front-end:

```
@if ($equipments)
@foreach ($equipments as $index => $equipment)
<tr wire:key="post-field-{{$equipment->Index}}">
    <td class="px-6...">
        <div class="flex...">
            <div class="...">
                <input wire:model="equipment.{{ $index }}.Equipment_Image" id="grid-password" type="file" placeholder=""
                    name="Equipment_Image">
            </div>
        </div>

    </td>
    <td class="px-6...">
        <button type="button" wire:click="removeElement({{$equipment->Index}})" class="close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </td>

</tr>
@endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: This is more of html-javascript thing rather than laravel. Use html input type "file" with multiple attribute to allow more than one items to be uploaded per input tag.

Comment: Every item in the list can only have one image, I don't want users to upload more than one image for every single item.

Comment: Oh my bad, then what you want to do is to use prevent modifier. Add a conditional delete button if input file tag has content.  And lastly add a button with wire:submit action to point to your livewire upload method.